# Get the Ad_click_ID in Android

Tags: android

If the user clicks on the Ad_clickID, It will redirect to URL and download the APK and install, after launching the APK how can we  get the ad_click_id in Android.

Comment: Have you seen: [Google Play Install Referrer API vs. INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47571503/295004)

Comment: We are not using play store. So, I cant use Install referrer... If we click on the ad, it will redirect to the our custom url, from there APK will download and install, After launching the app need to fetch the ad_click_id. Thanks in Advance.